# How to restore transaction log with multiple files

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I restore database logs like :

```
RESTORE LOG [paytrn] FROM  DISK = N'C:\backup\log.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 100
GO
RESTORE LOG [paytrn] FROM  DISK = N'C:\backup\log.trn' WITH  FILE = 2,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 100
GO
```

But have many files , is there any way to restore all files without write restore for every file? Something like :

```
RESTORE LOG [paytrn] FROM  DISK = N'C:\backup\log.trn' WITH  FILE = ALL,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 100
```

Comment: You can probably write a quick script to generate the restore commands... then it becomes copy and paste...

Comment: @samyi can you give me example ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restore multiple transaction log files in one shot. They are additive files and must be loaded in sequential order from start to finish. Unfortunately they do not function like differential backups.

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking. He's just talking about syntax.

Comment: If that is the case my answer is still valid as there is no syntax available for the requested action. Transaction log backups must be loaded in sequential order one at a time. You have to explicitly define every transaction log file you wish to use while restoring a database. There is just no easy way to do it.